# Visual Studio 2017 files in source control

Tags: javascript, git, version-control, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a mobile app project with Ionic, Angular and Cordova.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 as my IDE.

When I test my app I deploy to the devices via Visual Studio and each time I change my device target the following files are changed:

```
    modified:   App1.jsproj
    modified:   App1.jsproj.user
    modified:   App1.sln
```

It creates a lot of noise on my git when I am working on a new feature.
However, I want other developers to be able to pull from my repo and be able to just open Visual Studio and have the app work.

Should I exclude the files from git in my situation?

Edit: 
In my jsproj file these values keep changing:

```
+    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Windows Phone">
+      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
+      <Platform>Windows Phone</Platform>
+    </ProjectConfiguration>
```

In my .sln file these values keep changing:

```
+VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26430.4
+ Debug|Windows Phone = Debug|Windows Phone
```

In my .user file these values keep chaning:

```
+  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Windows Phone'">
+    <DebuggerFlavor>AndroidEmulator</DebuggerFlavor>
+    <AndroidEmulatorID>AndroidInstallEmulators;Install Android emulators...</AndroidEmulatorID>
+  </PropertyGroup>
```

I don't know why the values keep changing and I don't know if I should be tracking them or not.

Comment: use your `.gitignore` file to exclude them. what is changing in the `.jsproj` and `.sln` file? it should be limited to `.user`. alternatively: you can decide which files you want to commit. You can exclude them if this is not a change you want to make _this time_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `skip-worktree` feature like described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/717372